# TFS 2012 how to delete all pending build requests of a build controller?

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration

I want to drop the build controller via TFS Administration Control but I get the below box in the snapshot.

[image]

I have delete all my build requests but I guess there are some one else builds still remain.

I have the admin right of TFS server.

How can we drop all the queueing build requests?

Comment: You should see the currently running builds in the Queued tab of the Build Explorer view, and you can abort them since you are an admin. Or are you looking for an automated solution?

Comment: How can we get to the Build Explorer to see all builds of all users of all team projects?

Comment: And no, I do not looking for automated solution.

Comment: Clicking All Build Definitions in the Team Explorer pane will give you all the builds of a specific team project, but I believe you have to repeat the process once for each team project (I cannot see a way to consolidate them all in a single view).

Comment: I see the same thing with you for each team project annoyance. That's why I ask.